Flutter Widget Test: CitySearchButton not behaving as expected
Problem Description:
I am testing the CitySearchButton widget, and I want to confirm that a CircularProgressIndicator is displayed when isLoading is true. However, the test does not pass.
Reproducible Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/components/city_search_button.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/view_model/city_search_state.dart';
import '../mocks/custom_mock_city_search_view_model.dart';
import '../view_model/providers/custom_mock_city_search_view_model_provider.dart';

void main() {
  group('CitySearchButton Tests', () {
    late CustomMockCitySearchViewModel mockViewModel;
    late ProviderContainer container;

    setUp(() {
      // Initialize the mock ViewModel
      mockViewModel = CustomMockCitySearchViewModel();
      // Initialize the ProviderContainer
      container = ProviderContainer(overrides: [
        customMockCitySearchViewModelProvider.overrideWithValue(mockViewModel),
      ]);
    });

    testWidgets('Displays CircularProgressIndicator when isLoading is true', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // Setting the ViewModel state
      mockViewModel.setState(CitySearchState(isLoading: true));

      // Building the widget under test
      await tester.pumpWidget(UncontrolledProviderScope(
        container: container,
        child: const MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: CitySearchButton(),
          ),
        ),
      ));

      // Pumping again to reflect the state
      await tester.pump();

      // Debugging the widget tree
      debugDumpApp();

      // Verifying that CircularProgressIndicator is displayed
      expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}

What I Have Tried:

Used pumpAndSettle(), but the result did not change.
Used debugDumpApp() to debug the widget tree, but the expected widget was not found.

Error Message:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching candidate
  Actual: _TypeWidgetFinder:<Found 0 widgets with type "CircularProgressIndicator": []>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/username/Flutter/weather_app/test/components/city_search_button_test.dart:64:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:168:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1013:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
# file:///Users/username/Flutter/weather_app/test/components/city_search_button_test.dart line 64
The test description was:
  Displays CircularProgressIndicator when isLoading is true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

CustomMock CitySearchViewModel Setup:
class CustomMockCitySearchViewModel extends Mock
    implements CitySearchViewModel {
  CustomMockCitySearchViewModel() {
    when(state).thenReturn(CitySearchState());
  }
}

Provider Container Setup:
final container = ProviderContainer(
  overrides: [
    customMockCitySearchViewModelProvider.overrideWithValue(mockViewModel),
  ],
);

Environment:

Flutter 3.16.3

Additional Information:

flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1
mockito: ^5.4.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What Did You Try?

I used pumpAndSettle() to ensure all animations and state changes were settled before checking for the CircularProgressIndicator.
I used debugDumpApp() to inspect the widget tree and confirmed that the expected state was not reflected.

What Were You Expecting?

I expected CircularProgressIndicator to be present in the widget tree when isLoading is set to true in the CitySearchState.
I expected the debugDumpApp() output to include the CircularProgressIndicator widget, indicating that the loading state was correctly handled by the CitySearchButton.

